# How to receive the second argument from this.$emit() in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom input element `my-input` in `MyInput.vue`:

```
<input :value="value" @input="inputOccurred($event.target.value)">
```

In my `inputOccurred` method, I am emitting `oninputoccurred` custom event and also passing the value:

```
inputOccurred: function(value){
     this.$emit('oninputoccurred', value);
}
```

But how can I receive the passed value from the parent component? And where does the second argument (value) go from `this.$emit()`?

```
 <my-input @oninputoccurred="printValue(<!-- How do I get the value here -->)"></my-input>
```

Comment: Ok, `:value="value"` will update the model `this.value`, then from inside the `inputOccurred` method you will have access to it so you dont need to pass it again. Then upon emit'ing the event `printValue` method will have been passed the `value`, so do `@oninputoccurred="printValue"` instead and just access it as a function argument `printValue (value)  {this.value = value}`

Comment: Basicly pass values using `v-bind:` and access as props, then emit values back to the parent.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't have a data property called value in my parent component. So I will not be able to access `this.value` inside `printValue` which is defined in the App.vue

Comment: Then what are you trying to send back from the component?

Comment: value, the second arg in this.$emit(). Now that you have made it clear I don't explicitly have to receive the second arg, I can now access value directly: `printValue: function(value){ console.log(value); }` A bit confusing and counter-intuitive though. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of sending a value to a component `:in` then internally setting the components model `this.value`, then upon `@input` send the current value back to the parent via emitting it.

```js
Vue.component('myInput', {
  template: '#input-template',
  props: ['in'],
  data () {
    return {
      value: this.in
    }
  },
  methods: {
    inputOccurred (e) {
      // set the model
      this.value = e.target.value
      this.$emit('on-out', this.value.split("").reverse().join(""))
    }
  }
});

//
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      value: 'Sent from parent, reverse by typing a value'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setValue (value) {
      this.value = value
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-input :in="value" @on-out="setValue"></my-input>
  
  {{ value }}
</div>

<template id="input-template">
  <input :value="value" @input="inputOccurred">
</template>
```